# Visual error from py scripts ran from UBuntu WSL

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pysimplegui

I use ubuntu on my windows OS and it uses WSL.

I run python scripts from it that use webdrivers that open up web-browsers and also a GUI from the PySimpleGui lib.

Lately when I run scripts that open these things the graphical stuff appears with horizontal lines everywhere like in the photos.

I have updated my drivers and have ran apt update but that has not helped.

I think I might have to upgrade some packages but I am afraid to upgrade them all. List of packages also included in the pictures.

Would anyone have advice if this is an outdated package problem? I will list the upgradable packages if anyone might know what one it might be.

Thank you,

Henry.

[image: PySimpleGui]

[image: Selenium ChromeWebDriver]

[image: packages 1]
[image: packages 2]
[image: packages 3]
[image: packages 4]
[image: packages 5]

I have updated my drivers and have ran apt update but that has not helped.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow we assist in programming. We don't fix computer problems in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also get this exact problem.  I would also like to find a solution.

A workaround is to use a python tjat is running in windows to run the script.  It doesnt have the same graphics bugs.

It can be launched from inside wsl with

```
cmd.exe /c python myprog.py
```

and if you need do `cd` into the dir, use `pushd`

```
cmd.exe /c  "pushd $(wslpath -w .) && python myprog.py"
```

Note that you will have to install the packages you need also in the windows python installation.